# Custom Google fonts not working with Flask

Tags: html, css, flask, google-font-api

I am currently trying to use Google Fonts to render a custom font on a webpage hosted on Flask however the font does not apply. When I try the same html and css files in my browser without Flask, the fonts show. Any reason why Google fonts may not work with Flask?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="googleFonts.css">
    <title>Google Fonts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="header">This is Google Fonts</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 .header {
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: check googleFonts.css is loading or not. check it in network in browser

Comment: Google Fonts is loading, since it works when I test it out dragging an HTML into browser, but not when accessing via a Flask server

Comment: Not google font, your CSS is not loading. I think. What is a position of your css file

Comment: Ah gotcha! The CSS file is in the same nested `templates` folder as the HTML, `application.py` is in the main folder.

Comment:  You should use the `static` folder for static content like CSS file here.

Comment: As PSKP said I would store the font in static folder (that you need to create) and then create a subfolder called css. It would look something like this PROJECT_NAME/static/css/FILE.css